# Enlarge the font size of a pie chart label

Tags: labeling, charts

I have

```
PieChart[
 {
  Labeled[10, "A", "RadialCallout"]
  , Labeled[20, "B", "RadialCallout"]
  }
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

I want to enlarge the fontsize of label "A"

How?

Comment: Use `Style`. `Style["A", FontSize -> 20]`

Comment: Actually, `Style["A", 20],` is all that is needed.